# In a Python class, what is the difference between creating a variable with the self syntax, and creating one without ?

Tags: python

What is the difference between creating a variable using the self.variable syntax and creating one without?

I was testing it out and I can still access both from an instance:

```
class TestClass(object):
    j = 10
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 20

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testInstance = TestClass()
    print testInstance.i
    print testInstance.j
```

However, if I swap the location of the `self`, it results in an error.

```
class TestClass(object):
    self.j = 10
    def __init__(self):
        i = 20

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testInstance = TestClass()
    print testInstance.i
    print testInstance.j  

>>NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

So I gather that self has a special role in initialization.. but, I just don't quite get what it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self` refers to the current *instance* of the class. If you declare a variable outside of a function body, you're referring to the class itself, not an instance, and thus all instances of the class will share the same value for that attribute.

In addition, variables declared as part of the class (rather than part of an instance) can be accessed as part of the class itself:

```
class Foo(object):
    a = 1

one = Foo()
two = Foo()

Foo.a = 3
```

Since this value is class-wide, not only can you read it directly from the class:

```
print Foo.a # prints 3
```

But it will also change the value for every instance of the class:

```
print one.a # prints 3
print two.a # prints 3
```

Note, however, that this is only the case if you don't override a class variable with an instance variable. For instance, if you created the following:

```
class Bar(object)
    a = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 2
```

and then did the following:

```
one = Bar()
two = Bar()
two.a = 3
```

Then you'd get the following results:

```
print Bar.a # prints "1"
print one.a # prints "2"
print two.a # prints "3"
```

As noted in the comments, assigning to `two.a` creates an instance-local entry on that instance, which overrides the `a` from `Bar`, hence why `Bar.a` is still 1 but `two.a` is 3.

Comment: Since `a` is a class variable, you can also access `Foo.a` directly

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa Quite true.

Comment: Another thing, if in the `__init__` method of foo you alter `self.a`, you do so only for that instance, so `Foo.a` is still unchanged.

Comment: To further explain kindall's first point: when you assign to a class attribute on an instance, you _create a new attribute on the instance_, you don't modify the value of the class attribute. If the attribute is a mutable object, you _can_ mutate it, and _that_ will be visible on all instances of the class. But assignment to an class attribute on an instance will add a new entry to the instance's `__dict__` which will always be retrieved before the class attribute. To illustrate this, just examine `__dict__` on `one` and `two` in the first example before and after the new assignments.

Comment: @kindall You're correct about the first example, and I've removed the incorrect portion. The second example (with `Bar`), however, is correct, and has been tested.

Answer (score 0):

`j` is a class variable as pointed by Amber. Now, if you come from C++ background, `self` is akin to the `this` pointer. While python doesn't deal with pointers, `self` plays the similar role of referring to current instance of the class.

In the python way, `explicit is better than implicit`. In C++, the availability of  `this` is conventionally assumed for each class. Python, on the other hand, explicitly passes `self` as first argument to each of your instance methods.

Hence `self` is available only inside the scope of your instance methods, making it `undefined` for the place from which you tried using it.

Since you're made to explicitly pass `self` to instance methods, you could also call it something else if you want to -

```
>>> class Foo:
...     b = 20
...     def __init__(them):
...             them.beep = "weee"
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.beep
'weee'
```